# Should I use jQuery controls instead of HTML/asp.net controls in most situations?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I'm relatively new to jQuery. To me, there's three sets of controls (html controls, asp.net controls, and jQuery controls). To build an asp.net web page, how should I choose which one to choose from if these three all have the same control (e.g., button). In other words, in what situation should I pick one over the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is to always use basic html in as many situations as possible. ASP.NET and jQuery controls end up generating standard html controls in the end, they just abstract away some aspects. Without a more specific question, it is very hard to say what you should use. It is probably not what you want to hear, but you need to better understand the differences between these three types and make pick the best option for the situation at hand.

That said, I find myself using standard html input controls as much as possible, and using jQuery for client-side interactions. With ASP.NET MVC this is much easier than WebForms; though it's possible in both. If you're in WebForms you may wish to use the built-in ASP.NET controls.

Comment: Thanks, Nate. I am using basic webForms for my webpage and have little  knowledge of MVC framework. Do you mean the jQuery is only easy/popular to be used under MVC framework rather than only WebForms situation?

Comment: @lwconquer, yes. In general jQuery is much more popular with MVC; there is no technical reason. WebForms has the built-in controls so the other controls are not always needed. That said, jQuery can be used in conjunction with WebForms controls.

Answer (score 1):

in all of the kind, at the end they are all HTML controls. It depends on situation, as you're just learning use in mist cases ASP.NET controls, and learn what they will look like on the page (after rendering into HTML). You should know the core.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix and match and even combine.

Lets say you wanted to collect a phone number. Lets say you wanted to make it visually appealing for someone to enter the phone number so that the text box auto formats (###) ### - ####. Sure you could use a ASP.NET RegEx validator for force a 10 digit phone number but that looks plain.

The solution? Use an ASP:Textbox control and mix in a jQuery format plugin (Like this one http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ ) and you can improve the look and behavior of the standard .NET controls.

Don't like your dropdown menus in ASP.NET? Combine an asp:Dropdown with Chosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

How about a slide show of some sort or a carousel? Thats easy too, combine an ASP:Repeater with a .NET data source of some kind to output some HTML that you can use a jQuery Carousel with.

jQuery empowers us to do things that simply wern't avalaible several years ago. With their solid framework and the numerous plugins various developers have created we have the world at out fingertips!